# How to get around with this conversion issue?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, dll, numbers

I created a GUI which inputs a value number into another program and stores them in `tags`. I have a weird conversion problem. When I input 8.5 I get back a string 8.500000000000000... so I use the `TryParse` and the `Double.ToString()` method to get around this issue. But the bizarre part is that when I try with 6.9  the string becomes 6.9000000005367431600000.I use 2 dll which might be the cause of this problem. I've read this [Decimals explanation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) but I don't understand how this can be fix my problem. How to get around with this conversion issue?

**My Conversion method**

```
    private bool TryWrite()
            {
// Read() returns a string(which represents int,double, float or string) read from another application
                string Oldcopy = _inTouchWrapper.Read(tagNameBox.Text);
// Write() Write my input number into the application stored in a specific tag
                _inTouchWrapper.Write(tagNameBox.Text, ValueBox.Text);
//OldCopy is to input back the old copy is the Write (new copy) cannot be performed
                string newCopy = _inTouchWrapper.Read(tagNameBox.Text);

                if (ValueBox.Text == Double.Parse(newCopy).ToString())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _inTouchWrapper.Write(tagNameBox.Text, Oldcopy);
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

More explanation about the software/and my code. The software has tags ex: Alarm1, TimeString...
Each tag has a type (int, real(a float), string) and a value. This value depends on the type. I cannot input 5.6 if the tag type is int. So I created this method which verifies is the input value can indeed be added in the software. *How it works*: I input a value in the software, read it back and if the added value matches with the read value, I indeed input it. Else, I input back the oldCopy.

Comment: Might be a 2 dll issue?   Did you test?  You can use .ToString("N1") to get one decimal.

Comment: @Blam, I still a novice programmer, I don't know how to test a dll well.
I've downloaded JustDecompile from Telerik and try to understand it, but I didn't create the dll. The person who did it told be that there might be a conversion issue in the dll.

Comment: @Blam Thanks, I haven't thought about the overloaded ToString. I've recently learned that some .net fcts are overloaded.

Comment: d = double.Parse("6.9"); System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString());  does not break 6.9 so something else is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that string "6.9" is not directly converted to double. If is first converted to float and then casted to double. Here is an example:

```
var f = float.Parse("6.9");
var d = (double)f;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString()); //6.90000009536743
```

*PS: Why you not have the same issue with '8.5' is that it can exactly be represented in binary form.*